# T pointer default value

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
class myclass {
  public:
    myclass();
  private:
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
myclass<T>::myclass() : value(T()) {}
```

If `T` is a pointer (e.g. `int*`), what's the default value (`int*()`)? Is it `nullptr` or plain zero? Is there any difference in this case?

Answer (score 4):

> What's the default value then? Is it nullptr or plain zero?

The pointer is a null pointer then. `nullptr` and `0` are interchangeable in this context.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it `nullptr` or plain zero? And is there any difference in this case?

The initialization syntax you are using is called [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). For pointers, it is same as [zero initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization). Hence, when `T` is `int*`, your code is equivalent to

```
template <typename T>
myclass<T>::myclass() : value(T(0)) {}
```

> And is there any difference in this case?

No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Per cppreference.com:

[Value Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

> ## Syntax
>
> `T();` (1)
>   ...
>
> Value initialization is performed in these situations:
>
> 1,5) when a nameless temporary object is created with the initializer consisting of an empty pair of parentheses [or braces (since C++11)];
>   ...
>
> The effects of value initialization are:
>
> 1) if T is a class type with at least one user-provided constructor of any kind, the default constructor is called; (until C++11)
>
> 1) if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-provided or deleted default constructor, the object is default-initialized; (since C++11)
>
> ---
>
> 2) if T is a non-union class type without any user-provided constructors, every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized; (until C++11)
>
> 2) if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor; (since C++11)
>
> ---
>
> 3) if T is an array type, each element of the array is value-initialized;
>
> 4) **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.**

[Zero Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)

> ## Syntax
>
> `T();` (2)
>   ...
>
> Zero initialization is performed in the following situations:
>
> ...
>   2) As part of value-initialization sequence for non-class types and for members of value-initialized class types that have no constructors, including value initialization of elements of aggregates for which no initializers are provided.
>   ...
>
> The effects of zero initialization are:
>
> - **If T is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral constant zero explicitly converted to T.**
> - If T is an non-union class type, all base classes and non-static data members are zero-initialized, and all padding is initialized to zero bits. The constructors, if any, are ignored.
> - If T is a union type, the first non-static named data member is zero-initialized and all padding is initialized to zero bits.
> - If T is array type, each element is zero-initialized
> - If T is reference type, nothing is done.

Which means that when `T` is *any* pointer type (eg: `int*`) , `T()` will be `0` converted to `T` (eg: `static_cast<int*>(0)`).  In C++11 and later, that is equivalent to `nullptr`, as a literal `0` is implicitly convertible to a pointer type, same as `nullptr`.